# White Noise Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, noise

Would this process be a white noise sequence?

> Consider the process $\{tY_t\}_{t = 1, . . . , 100}$, where $Y_t$ are independently, normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1.

The process holds for the two first conditions which are:

- $$ E(Y_t) = 0 $$
- $$ Var (Y_t) = 1 $$

I am unsure about the third condition which states that:

- $$ E(Y_t,Y_s) = 0  $$

My intuitive guess would be that this condition will still hold as the sequence is independent.

Comment: Are you asking about the process $(Y_t)$ or $(tY_t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the process is not white noise, because the variance is not constant, it depends on $t$. We have that
$$
\operatorname{Var}[tY_t]=t^2.
$$

However, the elements of this sequence are uncorrelated. Since $Y_t$ and $Y_s$ are independent,
$$
\operatorname E[sX_stX_t]=st\operatorname EX_s\operatorname EX_t=0.
$$
We do not need independence for the first equality, non-correlation is sufficient, but independence implies non-correlation.

Comment: Oh now I feel silly! Thanks for the answer. 

So multiplying this sequence with the Index t still yield uncorrelation?

$$ E[X s X t ]=EX s EX t =0. $$

Comment: @Siroffinance No problem, you're welcome! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question more readable. I overlooked that we actually have $tY_t$. The sequence would still be independent, but it would not be white noise anymore since the variance would be equal to $t^2$ (see my edit).

Comment: Thank you again. Will try to apply MathJax in the future.